What are they fighting over in Pakistan?
There is at least one insurgency in progress in Pakistan, in the Baluchistan Province, which seems to involve some sort of independence movement.
Who are the parties to the conflict and what is the substance of why they feel the need to fight (i.e. what are the grievances of the insurgents)?
For example, why do those who are seeking it want Baluchistan want to be independent of Pakistan?

Insurgency in Balochistan - Wikipedia - drivers of insurgency would be a good start.

They're also fighting in the north, TTP and all that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insurgency_in_Khyber_Pakhtunkhwa I think the number of attacks has been greater from the latter. AFAICT it has turned in a cross-border  war too https://www.bbc.com/news/articles/c7289yvl84po

Why do people ever want self-determination or independence? This seems to be a matter of psychology as much as specific political grievances.

The BLA, which has claimed the most recent attacks in Balochistan is nominally fighting for independence, or at least more autonomy. There's a strong ethnic/xenophobic component to their movement. The latest attacks somewhat resemble those from 2009:

Most BLA members are drawn from the Marri or Bugti tribes [...]
On April 15, 2009 during an interview on a Pakistani news station, alleged leader Brahamdagh Khan Bugti urged Baloch people to kill any non-native Baloch residing in Balochistan whether they were military or civilian. Following Bugti’s interview, targeted killings of Punjabi civilians broke out in Balochistan. The BLA claimed credit for inciting the violence, but it is unclear if the killings were carried out by Baloch residents responding to the BLA’s calls for violence or if the killings were carried out directly by the BLA. According to the BLA, an estimated 500 Punjabis were killed following Bugti’s television interview. Many of the Punjabi killed were multi-generational residents of Balochistan.
[...] As of 2018, the group has focused its attention on ridding Balochistan of Chinese and Pakistani influence.  A senior commander of the BLA accused China and Pakistan of plundering the country’s natural resources and perpetrating atrocities on Baloch in order to eliminate Baloch identity. In November 2018, the BLA opened fire on the Chinese consulate in Karachi in the hope of damaging Sino-Pakistani relations amidst the development of new international agreements.

So, anti-China is another angle to BLA. Whether these are different factions with different priorities, I'm not entirely sure. Anyhow, as for their rhetoric on that anti-China angle, here's something from May 2022:

After last month’s attack – carried out by 30-year-old “Shari Baloch”, the first female suicide bomber of the BLA’s Majeed Brigade – separatists warned China there would be more attacks on Chinese nationals and Chinese projects in Pakistan. In a video that appeared on social media the day after the bombing, the BLA demanded that China quit Balochistan or face further retaliatory action. The video shows a masked BLA commander speaking in English and addressing China’s President Xi Jinping directly. “The Baloch Liberation Army guarantees you that CPEC will fail miserably on Baloch land … you still have time to quit Balochistan, or you will witness a retaliation from Baloch sons and daughters that you will never forget”.

Pakistan and the Chinese press often accuse India of supporting the BLA, and sometimes Iran too. (Conversely Iran accuses Pakistan of supporting somewhat similar groups across the border, or at least of turning a blind eye towards them. The smaller and Marxist-inspired BLF has fought against both Iran and Pakistan. The Salafi-inspired Jaish ul-Adl, mostly against Iran.)
This is just in Balochistan. Further north in Khyber Pakhtunkhwa, it's mostly the Taliban-inspired TTP that's fighting, AFAICT to impose an emirate in Pakistan, or at least in the northern part of it. (The Afghan Taliban government itself does not recognize the border [Durand line] that separates Afghanistan from Pakistan. But they also disclaim explicit support for the TTP.) The TTP also targeted Chinese interests sometimes.  Some BLA factions (of the Mazar tribe at least) appear to have joined the TTP, which perhaps explains them adopting suicide-bombing tactics, among other things.

But to [re-]focus a bit more on the BLA through their own words, if we trust The Balochistan Post, the Pakistani crackdown on the BSO-Azad student organization (2008-2011) drove many of them, including its leader into the arms of the BLA, which partly explains the renewed strength of the insurgency/attacks. According to the same piece (which contains a lengthy interview with the current BLA chief) in 2017-2018, the BLA cut ties with some of their leadership in exile [in Europe/London], becoming a more harcore and attacks oriented organization.

Our opponents allege that we are taking the liberation struggle to the extremes, and we are changing the direction of Baloch liberation struggle through self-sacrificing attacks. We are asked to respond to these allegations. Actually, we do not feel it necessary to respond to this as we accept these allegations. They are saying the same things, which we intend to do. Absolutely, we want to concentrate on the armed struggle, in fact, our aim is to introduce even further intensity in this war.
We utterly believe that Baloch nation’s human, civic and political rights are linked to independence and this independence can only be achieved through a strong and powerful resistance against the enemy. We firmly believe that we will break the backbone of the enemy through such self-sacrificing attacks. [...] We will never compromise on the direction of this struggle and will always resist intentions of transforming it into an NGO for human rights. We cannot tolerate the repetition of mistakes of past.
[...] Baloch Liberation Army’s struggle is for the historical and ideological boundaries of the Baloch nation. BLA does not accept the division of Baloch land, which resulted through demarcations of Durand Line, Goldsmid Line or the boundaries of so-called Pakistani provinces. Our struggle is to restore the Baloch state with boundaries demarcated by Noori Naseer Khan. BLA will not compromise for even a second on these historical and ideological boundaries.

The last bit appears to refer to the greatest extent attained by the Khanate of Kalat.

The NGO bit might be an allusion to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_for_Baloch_Missing_Persons

They say that they don't want to become "an NGO for human rights," but then they also claim that "Baloch nation’s human, civic and political rights are linked to independence," the same independence that they apparently advocate, which, by virtue of them not being a government, would seem to position them as an NGO for human rights (from their own perspective, at least). So are they not actually pursuing independence, or do they see themselves as a governmental organization (i.e. the future government of Balochistan)?

Well, I guess there's also the possibility that they do not actually believe independence will promote human rights. Which, yeah, considering that they seem to like suicide bombings and murdering Punjabi people, might be true if the independence is on their terms, but probably does not fit with the image that they are trying to promote in that interview.

@Obie2.0: true, but in the PR releases on the same site, e.g. on their latest attack, they claim to have killed only soldiers. So, the PR itself is consistent, but unless the MSM press in Bangladesh is inventing the civilian casualties... N.B. as I reread their updated presser (they upped at  least the number of casualties they claim to have inflicted from ~100 to 130 now) they use "enemy personnel", which is more ambiguous, but they focus on their claim of attacking a "Bela headquarters", which I'm not too sure what it refers to.

@Obie2.0: FWTW, they seem to claim those were soldiers on leave or some such (possibly just conscripts) "the majority of the slain personnel were traveling in civilian clothes on passenger buses when they were identified and killed by BLA fighters" https://www.satp.org/terrorism-update/23-punjabi-travellers-shot-dead-by-bla-in-balochistan OTOH they also claim to have killed some "collaborators" with the Pak army. And "Bela" is a city in the region... [Well, pop 20K]
